# How to use "Distinct" in QueryBuilder of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, query-builder

I have one table. I want to join this table to itself. I.e. it will be a table which is created from the two same tables. The problem is that the table(TableAdapert in QueryBuilder) has duplicate rows. I know that in SQL I can use an operator "Distinct". However, when I try to write "dictinct" in QueryBuilder then I always catch an error.

```
SELECT     STUDENT.ID, STUDENT.NAME, STUDENT.SURNAME, STUDENT.IDGROUP, 
STUDENT_1.ID AS Expr1, STUDENT_1.NAME AS Expr2, 
STUDENT_1.SURNAME AS Expr3
FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN
                  STUDENT AS STUDENT_1 ON STUDENT.IDGROUP = STUDENT_1.ID
```

Where is it possible to write "Distinct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally "Distict" is following after the SELECT.

like this

SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT.ID, STUDENT.NAME, STUDENT.SURNAME, STUDENT.IDGROUP, 
STUDENT_1.ID AS Expr1, STUDENT_1.NAME AS Expr2, STUDENT_1.SURNAME AS Expr3
FROM STUDENT 
INNER JOIN STUDENT AS STUDENT_1 ON STUDENT.IDGROUP = STUDENT_1.ID